# hibernate oracle identifier is too long ORA-00972

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

Im stuck with this problem. The database schema is provided by someone else so I cant simply change names. I tried add everywhere proper annotations, maybe I'm missing something (obvious)?

Here is my full mapping (quite many classess), I'll ommit getter/setters.

The problem is when hibernate is trying to get all `List<ControlRuleAttrib> controlRuleAttribs`

**Controle Rule**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTROL_RULE")
public class ControlRule implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ID")
 private Long id;
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_TYPE_ID")
 @ForeignKey(name = "CONTROL_RULE_TYPE_ID")
 private ControlRuleType controlRuleType;
 @Column(name = "JOB_NM")
 private String jobname;
 @Column(name = "LIBRARY_NM")
 private String libraryname;
 @Column(name = "TABLE_NM")
 private String tablename;
 @Column(name = "COLUMN_NM")
 private String columnname;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB", joinColumns = {
  @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
 })
 private List < ControlRuleAttrib > controlRuleAttribs;
}
```

**ControlRuleAttrib**

```
@Table(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB")
@Entity
public class ControlRuleAttrib {
 @EmbeddedId
 private ControlRuleAttribPK controlRuleAttribPK;

 @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_VALUE")
 private String attributeValue;
}
```

**ControleRuleAttribPK**
Question here is, is it possible to somehow get Entity `ControlRuleAttribType` from `ControlRuleAttrib`? As you can see below `ControlRuleAttribTypeId` is the id of `ControleRuleAttribType`. I'd like to get whole object isteand of integer.

```
@Embeddable
public class ControlRuleAttribPK implements Serializable {
 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ID")
 private Long controlRuleId;

 @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_SEQ_NUM")
 private Integer attributeSeqNum;

 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_ID")
 private Integer controlRuleAttribTypeId;
}
```

**ControleRuleAttribType**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE")
public class ControlRuleAttribType implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_ID")
 private Integer id;
 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_NM")
 private String typename;
 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_DESC")
 private String typedesc;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_TYPE_ID")
 @ForeignKey(name = "CONTROL_RULE_TYPE_ID")
 private ControlRuleType controlruletype;
}
```

**ControleRuleType**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTROL_RULE_TYPE")
public class ControlRuleType implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_TYPE_ID")
 private Integer id;
 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_TYPE_NM")
 private String typename;
 @Column(name = "CONTROL_RULE_TYPE_DESC")
 private String typedesc;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is stacktrace:

https://gist.github.com/a30dd9ce534d96bb9a97

As you'll find out, it fails here:

> at
>   com.execon.controllers.main.MainPageController.getMainPage(MainPageController.java:33)
>   [classes:]

and this is it:

```
List<ControlRule> list = SessionFactoryUtils.openSession(
    sessionFactory ).createQuery( "from ControlRule" ).list();
System.out.println( list );
```

every object which mapping I added, has `toString()` method declared like this:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String s = "ControlRule{";
    s += "id=" + id.toString();
    s += ", controlRuleType=" + controlRuleType;
    s += ", jobname='" + jobname + '\'';
    s += ", libraryname='" + libraryname + '\'';
    s += ", tablename='" + tablename + '\'';
    s += ", columnname='" + columnname + '\'';
    s += ", controlRuleAttribs=" + controlRuleAttribs;
    s += '}';
    return s;
}
```

And hibernate request:

https://gist.github.com/c8584113522757a4e0d8/4f31dc03e7e842eef693fa7ba928e19d27b3ca26

Help please :)

**EDIT 2**

Well after reading @Jens answer, I did some changes in the code. First I did as you wrote and it gave error:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering
>   com.execon.models.controlrules.ControlRuleAttrib from
>   com.execon.models.controlrules.ControlRule has the wrong number of
>   column. should be 3

I guess this is right, as I have composite primary key.

Then I tried it this way:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false),
                @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false),
                @JoinColumn(name = "ATTRIBUTE_SEQ_NUM", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        })
private List<ControlRuleAttrib> controlRuleAttribs;
```

Quite close but it gives me the following exception:

> Repeated column in mapping for collection..

So finally I removed

```
joinColumns = 
{
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
}
```

And everything compiled except that when I try to reach collection, Hibernate is doing following query:

https://gist.github.com/c88684392f0b7a62bea5

The last line, is `controlrul0_.CONTROL_RULE_CONTROL_RULE_ID=?` while it should be `controlrul0_.CONTROL_RULE_ID=?`.

Is there anyway I can make it work? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling with this for last few hours I finally make it working within my project. The thing I did was this:

**ControlRule**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "controlRuleAttribPK.controlRuleId")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ControlRuleAttrib> controlRuleAttribs;
```

Basically pointing that the collection should use controlRuleId from composite primary key. So far its working great!

Answer (score 0):

I do not clearly understand which identifier is too long, but I can propose that you can try to change `@Id` annotated field types from `Integer` to `Long`. And it will be great to get some detailed info (stack trace etc.) about your problem.

Comment: So, you've got Oracle error `ORA-00972`. It is described [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00972.php). The problem is long DB object names, so only solution that I can propose - shorten names. Maybe JPA provider generates very long aliases, but I think that this situation is almost impossible (even if the aliases are taken into account).

Comment: THat's the problem :/ Im writting stuff for company which provides us with their own data scheme and nothing I can really do with object names

Comment: Ooops!.. I did not notice your hibernate log. You can see there select ... ,controlrul0_.controlRuleAttribs_CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_ID as controlR3_1_ , ... from CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB controlrul0_ inner join .... controlRuleAttribs_CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_ID seems to be not valid column name. So, the problem is in `@JoinTable`. You can try to set `referencedColumnName` attribute to `@JoinColumn` annotation. Else you can browse [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the column

```
CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB.controlRuleAttribs_CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_ID
```

Which is so long it can't possibly exist in your database. I don't see in the question any hint how it is actually named, but I am assuming the proper name is

```
CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB.CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_ID
```

So the question is: Why is hibernate trying to access this column. The table it is in is a mapping table which is mapped in hibernate as:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private List<ControlRuleAttrib> controlRuleAttribs;
```

If you look at the @JoinTable annotation you'll notice that it defines the table name as it is used and a join column. But a mapping table has two sets of join columns. The second on is not specified. Therefore the NamingStrategy you configured or if you didn't configured any the default is used. Just specify the other set of join columns using the attribute inverseJoinColumns and all should be fine.

The complete annotation should look like:

```
@JoinTable(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CONTROL_RULE_ATTRIB_TYPE_ID")})
```

Note: I have no idea if you need any of the nullable, updatable stuff on that column as well.

See also the [documentation of the JoinTable annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html)

Comment: I editedd according to your suggestions, please see my edited post