# eclipselink oracle identifier is too long ORA-00972

Tags: oracle, jpa, jpql

There is strange problem from JPA (EclipseLink) and Oracle Database.

The following JPQL is expected:

```
SELECT w 
  FROM WfmStatusGroup w 
       LEFT JOIN w.statuses ws 
       LEFT JOIN ws.wfmTransList1 wt 
 WHERE wt.wfmWorkflowId = :wfmWorkflowId
```

But i'm getting following error:

> ORA-00972: Identifier is too long

Also following query generated in output.

```
SELECT t1.WFM_STATUS_GROUP_ID, t1.SYSTEM_ID, t1.WFM_STATUS_GROUP_DESC, 
       t1.WFM_STATUS_GROUP_NAME 
  FROM VERITECH_DEMO.WFM_STATUS_GROUP t1 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (WFM_STATUS_GROUP_WFM_STATUS t3 
                JOIN VERITECH_DEMO.WFM_STATUS t0 
                   ON (t0.WFM_STATUS_ID = t3.statuses_WFM_STATUS_ID)) 
            ON (t3.WfmStatusGroup_WFM_STATUS_GROUP_ID = t1.WFM_STATUS_GROUP_ID) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (WFM_STATUS_WFM_TRANSITION t4 
                JOIN VERITECH_DEMO.WFM_TRANSITION t2 
                  ON (t2.WFM_TRANSITION_ID = t4.wfmTransList1_WFM_TRANSITION_ID)) 
            ON (t4.WfmStatus_WFM_STATUS_ID = t0.WFM_STATUS_ID) 
 WHERE (t2.WFM_WORKFLOW_ID = ?)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This error states that you have a field name or an object name that is bigger than the oracle can handle, for instance this `wfmTransList1_WFM_TRANSITION_ID` has 31 chars and oracle only accept 30 chars for a field name.

See this answer here on SO: [Change table/column/index names size in oracle 11g or 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248318/change-table-column-index-names-size-in-oracle-11g-or-12c)

Comment: Regarding this answer, it is impossible to change character size, right?

Comment: Yes, you can't do this on oracle

Comment: wfmTransList1_WFM_TRANSITION_ID That one auto generated from JPA. I don't need to shortest entity name. Are there any way?

Comment: I think you can use aliases for your entities

Comment: Can you provide some example for that? I'm new of JPA. Thank you

Comment: I think this post will help you. But you will have to make some changes on your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414094/hibernate-oracle-identifier-is-too-long-ora-00972